# R: Slicing a grouped data frame conditional on a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a group, a condition that differs by group, and an index within each group:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)), 
                 condition = rep(c(0,1,1), each = 3), 
                 index = c(1:3,1:3,2:4))

> df
  group condition index
1     A         0     1
2     A         0     2
3     A         0     3
4     B         1     1
5     B         1     2
6     B         1     3
7     C         1     2
8     C         1     3
9     C         1     4
```

I would like to slice the data within each group, filtering out all but the row with the lowest index. However, this filter should only be applied when the condition applies, i.e., `condition == 1`. My solution was to compute a ranking on the index within each group and filter on the combination of condition and rank:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = order(index)) %>%
  filter(case_when(condition == 0 ~ TRUE,
                   condition == 1 & rank == 1 ~ TRUE))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
  group condition index  rank
  <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int>
1 A             0     1     1
2 A             0     2     2
3 A             0     3     3
4 B             1     1     1
5 C             1     2     1
```

This left me wondering whether there is a faster solution that does not require a separate ranking variable, and potentially uses slice_min() instead.

Comment: You can use `slice` with `which.min()`

Comment: I may not fully understand how which.min() works, but that does not account for the condition, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to keep all cases where the condition is zero or the index equals the minimum index.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(condition == 0 | index == min(index))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group condition index
  <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 A             0     1
2 A             0     2
3 A             0     3
4 B             1     1
5 C             1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    slice(unique(c(which(condition == 0), which.min(index))))
```

Comment: I have a question very similar to the OP, but instead of filtering I would need to apply a function. For example, using `group_map`, I apply custom function on my grouped data frame. That works. But, now, within that group I would need to apply the same function in chunks of 12 instead of the complete group df. For example if  there are 30 rows in the group. I would like to apply the function in chunks of 12 i.e 12 +12 +6 ...so would get 3 different outputs for the same group. Wondering if you have previously answered this ?any leads would be helpful.